# Dart / flutter widget test, Text Widgets are not found either by key nor by text

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-test, cubit

I implemented an app using WeatherAPI like in the ResoCoder example. I now want to test if every text widget is showing correct information but I already fail in finding the text widgets (I used this guide https://resocoder.com/2021/01/02/flutter-integration-test-tutorial-firebase-test-lab-codemagic/). I tried it by using find.byKey() (of course set some keys before) and find.byText() but none worked.

My test code:

```
testWidgets('Infos are displayed', (WidgetTester tester) async {
      await tester.pumpWidget(MaterialApp(home: WeatherScreen()));
      await tester.pump();
      final tempField = find.byKey(ValueKey("temperature"));
      
      expect(tempField, findsOneWidget);
      expect(find.text('humidity'), findsOneWidget);
    });
```

I always get the error that no those widgets where found:

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY FLUTTER TEST FRAMEWORK ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following TestFailure object was thrown running a test:
  Expected: exactly one matching node in the widget tree
  Actual: _KeyFinder:<zero widgets with key [<'temperature'>] (ignoring offstage widgets)>
   Which: means none were found but one was expected
```

And my screen widget:

```
class WeatherScreen extends StatelessWidget {Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
          child: BlocBuilder<WeatherCubit, WeatherBaseState>(
        bloc: WeatherCubit(weatherRepository: WeatherRepository())..getWeather(),
        builder: (context, state) {
          if (state is LoadingWeather) {
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          } else if (state is WeatherLoaded) {
            return Column(my widget stuff with text widgets to be found);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The weather screen uses `BlocBuilder` and when testing, you are not providing any BLoC to this widget. What you should do, is to wrap your `MaterialApp` or `WeatherScreen` with BlocProvider and provide your `WeatherCubit`, e.g.:

```
await tester.pumpWidget(
  MaterialApp(home: 
    BlocProvider<WeatherCubit>.value(
      value: weatherCubit,
      child: WeatherScreen(),
    )
  ),
);
```

Before that, you should also mock the `weatherCubit` value and define a wanted state. You could find a simple example here: https://github.com/felangel/bloc/blob/master/examples/flutter_counter/test/counter/view/counter_view_test.dart